# Method required by Interface not always meaningful

Tags: c#, interface, repository-pattern

From a C# class, I have access to a set of WCF web services that talk to a mainframe via Verastream Host Integrator.  It is basically fancy screen scraping.  The web services are all about either retrieving or updating data - no business logic - and so my thought is to build a data (transform?) layer using a repository pattern.

All that being said, my repository classes all implement an IRepository interface that requires a Retrieve() and an Update().  For the tiny percentage of repository classes that face a service with a retrieve, but no update, what do I do as a best practice?  Do I just leave the Update method throwing a NotImplementedException(), and if so, how do I communicate to anyone who uses my class that Update() is not broken, but not to be used.

Comment: Making the method a No-op does not make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I just leave the Update method throwing a NotImplementedException()

Use `NotSupportedException` instead.

> how do I communicate to anyone who uses my class that Update() is not
>   broken, but not to be used

There's something called ***documentation***!

In addition, `NotSupportedException` is a good indication of that `Update` isn't supported for some given service implementation. It's not broken but not supported.